# Fun Friday: This puzzle does what NintenDONT

Tags: knowledge, crosswords, video-games

It's Friday, lunch is over, and why get back to work - when you can relax with a quick 5 minutes video game puzzle!

Enjoy!

[image]

---

Text Version

> ----- --- -------- | Gotta Go Fast
> --------- --- | Frog loving character, and this game’s baddie “Evil” are both the same animal
>  ------ --- | Bob the Killer Fish and this game’s namesake weapon are both this colour.
> ------- ----- | The lead designer also created Wing War, Alien Storm and this game.
> -------- | Upon starting, you are told to rise from something this game would jump off cliffs into.
> --- --- | The only failure condition in this game was if the clock did this.
> ------ ------ | In the same genre, this game was one of the first fully 3D games.
> ---- --- ------- | The bridge level shares the name of the area that this game’s protagonist begins his journey.

Comment: I am genuinely looking forward to these puzzles now, they're very fun to work on.

Comment: I am guessing that these are NOT Nintendo games, right :D

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Heheh very correct. These are all games from one specific console - which the title should give away.

Comment: cool puzzle. not challenging enough you should have restricted this puzzle to anyone born 2005+. :)

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but what is the significance of the zig-zag arrows in the non-text version?

Comment: @jamesdlin I was trying to imply that the previous answer relates to the first part of the clue, that leads to the next answer. But I'm still trying things out to find what works best/makes the links most clear - so should hopefully be clearer in the next one.

Comment: What nintendo dont... Hmmm... Securing USB? :) ( https://fail0verflow.com/blog/2018/shofel2/ )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Gotta Go Fast!

> Sonic the Hedgehog

Frog loving character, and this game’s baddie “Evil” are both the same animal

> The frog-loving character is Big the Cat. An evil cat is the villain of **Earthworm Jim** (thanks to Kant1 for finding that one)

Bob the Killer Fish and this game’s namesake weapon are both this colour.

> Golden Axe

The lead designer also created Wing War, Alien Storm and this game.

> Altered Beast

Upon starting, you are told to rise from something this game would jump off cliffs into.

> I believe this is a reference to the famous line "Rise from your graves!" from Altered Beast (aka "WISE FWOM YOUR GWAVES"). Jumping off cliffs into a grave? Has to be **Lemmings.**

The only failure condition in this game was if the clock did this.

> Out Run

In the same genre, this game was one of the first fully 3D games.

> Virtua Racing

The bridge level shares the name of the area that this game’s protagonist begins his journey.

> Ecco the Dolphin

Title:

> They are all games released for the SEGA Genesis/Mega Drive, which had the advertising slogan: "Genesis does what Nintendon't".

Hidden message:

> The first letters of each game spell out **SEGA LOVE**.

Comment: Everything you've got there is perfect. Just got to find a way to make "Run Out" into the name of a game, and add the answer for a game with "Evil the Cat". There's also a (minor) hidden message in the answers you can get.

Comment: @Bilkokuya Pretty sure I've got everything now.

Comment: And that's a bingo! Nice work!

Answer (score 3):

Is 1

> Sonic The Hedgehog who goes fast (Gotta go Faster) and is from SEGA

Comment: Absolutely correct on (1).

Answer (score 2):

number 2 is

> earthworm jim if i'm not mistaken

Comment: Spot on for (2)